# Faster/More Django-ish way of querying large XML file that's using some really slow XPath

Tags: xml, django, xpath, elementtree

One of the functions in my views.py file in django has the following code:

```
from lxml import etree
f = etree.parse("path/to/file/k2.xml")
for item in charList:
    first += f.xpath(u"//character[item='"+item+"']/path/to/entry[@type='on']/text()")
    second += f.xpath(u"//character[item='"+item+"']/path/to/entry[@type='off']/text()")
```

This loads a 14mb XML file, scans through until it finds the correct item and adds two values to two variables using XPath.

This is really slow - 5 to 6 seconds, which is unacceptable for a high traffic site.

Django teaches you to not have a database call for each query, but instead have a permanent connection in the settings.py file - but thats if you're using SQL, not XML.

Is there some way of speeding this up, perhaps by always having the xml file in memory?

Comment: I've migrated the XML file into a MySQL database which is much faster. But this question still stands :/

Answer (score 1):

Doing XPath across a 14MB XML file is going to be slow, especially if you are using `//` as the root of the Query. This will force the processer to find *every* node and check the validitity of the Xpath against it.

If you can, break the file up into smaller documents - remember XML is a document based format, does all of your content *need* to be in the one file?

If you have to use such a large file, then try and get the most complete XPath you can. If you know the content is only in one of the branchs of the root ndoe, specify that. Even a small change at the root of an Xpath can have big impact on speed.